# node-config Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module /default.js

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, ecma, node-config

I am using ESM in my node project. Added `"type": "module"` in package.json

```
// index.js

import config from 'config'
```

```
// default.js

export default {
  time: 123,
  ...
  ...
}
```

But getting error in [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config)

```
Error: Cannot parse config file: '/home/Documents/.../config/default.js': Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/Documents/.../config/default.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /home/Documents/.../config/default.js from /home/Documents/.../node_modules/config/parser.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename default.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /home/Documents/.../package.json.
```

I can fix this by adding `default.cjs` instead of `default.js` but as I am using ESM so I am expecting it to work with `.js` extension also. am I missing something??. I can add `.json` also but I have big config variables and dynamic values that is why using `.js`.

Thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/node-config/node-config/wiki/Special-features-for-JavaScript-configuration-files you can not use ESM for configuration files but must use one of the other [supported formats](https://github.com/node-config/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files#file-formats).

> Loading files as ESM is not yet supported. So .mjs or .js when "type":"module" or --experimental-modules will not work.

But there is a work-around.
For example you could have the following structure, where **dynamic.js** is where you have *big config variables and dynamic values*:

```
.
├── config
│   ├── dynamic.js
│   └── test.cjs
├── index.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── config
│   ├── json5
│   └── minimist
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

You **must** tell nodejs that you use esm. So in your **package.json** you will want to have:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=test node index.js"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

In the beginning of your **index.js** file, you want to import [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config).

```js
import config from 'config';

const {default:configVariable} = await config.get('variable');

console.debug(configVariable.foo);
```

In the above case you could write "Hello World!" to your terminal if **config/test.cjs** and **config/dynamic.js** has the following:

```js
'use strict'

module.exports = {
    variable: import('./dynamic.js')
}
```

*test.cjs*

```js
export default {
    v1: 'var1',
    v2: 'var2',
    foo: 'Hello World!'
}
```

*dynamic.js*

The result of the above should then be:

```
$ npm start

> start
> NODE_ENV=test node index.js

Hello World!
```

Obviously, you can rename `variable` and `configVariable` to what-ever you want.

In my test, I had no issue with the above way of exporting esm as a Promise. But if you do get any issue with with that, you might solve it by wrapping `import()` in `require('config/raw').raw`.
See: https://github.com/node-config/node-config/wiki/Special-features-for-JavaScript-configuration-files#using-promises-processstdout-and-other-objects-in-javascript-config-files.

Comment: it is working after adding `.cjs` but I want to keep `.js` and export module with esm syntax which is currently not working. no sure `config` npm supports ESM or not?

Comment: If you mean [node-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) then yes it does. You need to add `"type": "module"` to your _package.json_ JSON. Then `.js` will be treated as `.mjs`.

Comment: Thank you dotnetCarpenter :). so it is working with `.mjs` extension but I was expecting it to work with `.js` extension also.

Comment: But I am getting a problem in `NODE_ENV=test` case. `NODE_ENV value of 'test' did not match any deployment config file names`. My file name is `test.mjs`.

Comment: @KiranMali I have updated my answer to specifically answer your use-case and made a git repo available as an example. https://github.com/dotnetCarpenter/SO_node-config

Comment: excellent work and information! thank you again :)

Comment: Glad that it works for and interesting problem as I am also using node-config. You might want to choose this as the answer, if it answer your question.

Comment: @KiranMali note that you can still have a `default.json5` file for default values. Those will be accessible via `config.get('defaultValue')`, where `defaultValue` is a exported variable in `default.json5`.